# Ionic 4: No emulator images (avds) found

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4

**I'm trying to emulate my ionic 4 app into Android Emulator
so I run the command:**

```
sudo ionic cordova emulate android --prod
```

**I get this error:**

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
42 actionable tasks: 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/esham/Desktop/magazine-app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/esham/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/esham/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/esham/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova emulate android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

## But I have 3 ADV on ADV Manager!!

And I could run any one of them by terminal for examble `emulator @Pixel_2_API_26`

**These the list of ADV I have:** `emulator -list-avds`

Pixel_2_API_26

Pixel_2_API_28

Pixel_3_API_28

**When I'm running command `android list avd` getting:**

```
The following Android Virtual Devices could not be loaded:
    Name: Pixel_3_API_28
    Path: /Users/esham/.android/avd/Pixel_3_API_28.avd
   Error: Google pixel_3 no longer exists as a device
---------
    Name: Pixel_2_API_26
    Path: /Users/esham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_26.avd
   Error: Google pixel_2 no longer exists as a device
---------
    Name: Pixel_2_API_28
    Path: /Users/esham/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_28_1.avd
   Error: Google pixel_2 no longer exists as a device
```

## So it doesn't make any sense! I have 3 ADV with all supported levels by cordova and keep saying `No emulator images (avds) found.`

These my environment setup on macOS:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding `--emulator=amulator_name`

So the full command will be:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --prod --emulator=Pixel_3_API_28
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run "ionic cordova run android" it's automatic run emulate by default. so try this. I hope it fixed your issue. firstly you check you Emulated Android path and it is properly downloaded or not. You run "ionic cordova resources" it checks all resources if fine or not. You need to be install anything or not. so try this.

Comment: No that's didn't fix the issue!, I need that emulator to get opened from the terminal by ionic as it should.